OpenScad - Alternative to large cylinder
I am using cylinders (with radius1 and radius2 to make slanted walls) with difference and intersection to form a complicated shape with lots of curves. In some cases I only use a small part of a massive ellipse in order to cut away a small piece with a very slight (but necessary) curve. Because I'm using only a small part of the cylinder, I need the resolution to be very high ($fa = 0.01), or it gets artifacts. Because of this, my relatively small model is taking ages to render (close to a minute to preview, and about half an hour to generate). This is getting unusable, because I need to generate a lot of these models with different permutations.
Practically speaking, I don't need the entire circle to be generated with such a high resolution. Is there a way to make a cylinder that it only needs to calculate a certain percentage of the arc? I would imagine that there's some way to do this with a polygon of sorts, but I don't know how.

I suspect that code that generates a polyhedron might be called for. Could you provide code that inefficiently creates the shape you need (at a lower resolution is fine as long as it's clearly specified that an answer needs to be something that can be scaled to a higher resolution), so answers can try to come up with an efficient way to generate that same shape?

Does something along these lines work for creating a part of the cylinder's arc? https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/11093/8758

That looks perfect. I need to slightly alter it, because as I said in the question, I need slanted walls, so I was using cylinder with two radii, but a polygon should do the trick. I'll post my final code if I get something I'm happy with.

When I used that code for it, it kept making crazy artifacts in preview mode, probably because there were too many walls in the middle of the circle.

This is what I ended up using:
function formula(x, exponent) = pow(x,exponent);
module scrape(start, finish, exponent, steepAngle, resolution) {
width = finish.x - start.x;
height = start.y - finish.y;

points = concat(
    [[width, formula(width,exponent)+1], [-1, formula(width,exponent)+1], [-1, 0]],
    [for(i=[0:width/resolution:width]) 
        [i, formula(i,exponent)]]
);
slantY = 5/tan(90-steepAngle);
linear_extrude(5, scale = (start.y + slantY)/start.y)
translate([start.x, finish.y])
scale([1,height/(formula(0, exponent)-formula(width,exponent)),1])
translate([0, -formula(width, exponent), 0])
    polygon(points);
}
scrape([1, 3], [5, 1], 1.4, 10, 30);

The "formula" function was originally the formula of a circle, sqrt(x*x - radius*radius), where radius was a number I played around with to affect how sharp the curve should be. But then I realized that with this code I could put any function I want, and I found that an exponential function produced better curves for what I needed.
